# Using a Mac on a TV - Increase size of elements without decreasing resolution

Tags: mac, hdtv

I have a Mac Mini hooked up to my 50" TV, which works great for lots of stuff like movies, but pretty poorly for things with text (menus, web browser).  Is there a way to make the default size of pretty much everything bigger without decreasing the resolution and making videos look crappy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately not yet. This is called resolution independence, it was officially announced for Leopard several months before shipping, but was not in the final product. Snow Leopard does not provide this feature.

Maybe in 10.7 ...

EDIT:

In a web browser, you can use <kbd>CMD</kbd>-<kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>CMD</kbd>-<kbd>-</kbd> for changing size of text.

Comment: Doesn't Mac OS have a simple way to increase the DPI? I'm using this in Windows; it's not perfect, but it's better than squinting just to read the text.

Comment: The only way I am aware of to increase the size of display elements is a zoom feature originally targetted to visually impaired people. But this decreases resolution and makes everything look crappy. Not what the OP is looking for.

Comment: I know that feature, and it really is bad. Is DPI changing available in Mac OS X?

Comment: I would say that DPI changing doesn't exist in Mac OS X but I am not 100% certain.

Comment: That's my impression as well. It's a shame, because it's a really useful feature, one that probably quite a lot of people would need. This is one domain where Microsoft seems to be way ahead of Apple, unfortunately.